# Updating order information affects another order information

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I'm trying to create a shopping cart kind of feature but in my scenario, user inputs a number and then a product gets added to a list to be displayed to the end user. The user can edit the price and quantity of the product and on update, the total amount of the price for that particular product should update as well.

The issue I'm facing right now is I enter two numbers, e.g. 1234 and 2345,  two "order" divs get generated and they both have price and quantity info for the user to change. Right now, when I change the price or quantity, it affects the total amount. For that product in particular, it works fine but since I entered two sku numbers, then both products total amounts get updated to the last change. So product 1 changes affect product 2 and vice versa.

I was wondering what can I do to fix these issues with this feature?

Here's a stackbiltz where I made the issue reproducible (Sorry for the crappy layout, this was a minimal sample that I could provide and I didn't want to spend time fixing the layout): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-nsy31g

Here's the code:

component:

```
 quantity = 1;
  retailPrice: number;
  totalAmount: number;
  extendedPrice: number;
  orderDetails: Array<IOrderDetails> = [];
  order: IOrderDetails;
  showDetails;

 validateNumber(number: number) {

   this.order = {
        _extendedPrice : 195.95,
        _retailPrice :  195.95,
        _quantity : 1,
        _productSkuKey : number,
        _lineItemNumber : 1
      }; 

      this.retailPrice = 195.95;
      this.extendedPrice = this.retailPrice * this.quantity;
      this.totalAmount = this.retailPrice * this.quantity;

      this.orderDetails.push(this.order);
      this.showDetails = true;

}
  updateTotal(retailPrice: number, number: number, indx: number) {
      this.quantity = number;
      this.extendedPrice = retailPrice * number;
      this.totalAmount = retailPrice * number;

  }
```

html:

```
<p>Calculate values</p>
<input #number type="number">
<button (click)="validateNumber(number.value)">enter</button>

<div *ngIf="showDetails">
  <div *ngFor="let order of orderDetails; let idx = index">
  <span>
        <div style="padding-left:20px;padding-bottom:10px;">Price* </div>
        <div><input #retailPrice class="transactionInput" style="width: 120px !important;" (keyup)="updateTotal(retailPrice.value, quantity.value, idx)" value="195.95" placeholder="Enter Price"/>x</div>
        </span>
        <span>
        <div style="text-align:center;padding-right:30px;padding-bottom:10px;">Qty</div>
        <div style="text-align:center;">
          <input #quantity type='number' value="1" min=1 oninput="validity.valid||(value=1);" class='qty' (change)="updateTotal(retailPrice.value, quantity.value,idx)"/> =</div>
    </span>
      <span>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
              Extended Price
            </div>
            <div><br></div>
            <div style="text-align:center;">
              USD ${{extendedPrice | number : '1.2-2'}}
            </div>
      </span>
</div>
 <div class="transactionDiv3">
      <div style="font-weight:bold; text-align:right; padding-right:20px; padding-bottom:20px;"> TotalOrderAmount $ {{totalAmount | number : '1.2-2'}} </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just iterate the issues:

1) updating the retail price or quantity show only update the order on that specific item/line and not the other order if I add another order to the list

2) total amount should be the sum of all orders in the list.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you've got a few problems. I've fixed them in https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-onsxlh

The problems are:

1. When you add a new order to the `orderDetails` array you are adding the same object, over and over, so if you modify one, you modify all:

   `this.orderDetails.push(this.order);`

Instead of this, you must clone the object, if you want `this.order` to be the default object:

```
this.orderDetails.push({...this.order});
```

Now, instead of adding the same object, we are adding a clone of the object.

2. When you call `updateTotal` you never use the `indx` of the order being modified. Instead, I don't really know what you are doing, modifying the same global variables (within the component) no matter which order you are editing. Besides, in the template, you are rendering the variable `extendedPrice` for every item, so it is logical that you always get the same value.

To fix this, you must render the value of `order._extendedPrice`, so it shows the cost of that item. Also, in `updateTotal` you must modify the values of the current order, not global variables:

```
updateTotal(retailPrice: number, number: number, indx: number) {
  const order = this.orderDetails[indx];
  order._retailPrice = retailPrice;
  order._quantity = number;
  order._extendedPrice = retailPrice * number;
  this.getTotal();
}
```

3. Finally, you're never calculating the sum of all orders. For that, I added the `getTotal` method, which using `reduce` sums the extended price of every order.

Now it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks Oscar. Btw, the stackbiltz url you shared isn't the right one. Can you share the direct url instead (the url address from your browser instead of the one on stackbiltz?)